Mysql: insert same value on a unique index, why locked?
Table like that:
CREATE TABLE `test_un_index` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_test_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

Transaction1:
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test_un_index(id) values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Transaction2:
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test_un_index(id) values (2);
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Why there will be a lock?
And if I change the index to not unique, the lock will not happen, why?
Thanks a lot!
I want to use "show engine innoDB status" to see the lock detail, but not found.

I tried the same code on MySQL 8.0.34. I get a different message: ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'test_un_index.idx_test_name'. This is expected message, in general.

You have not committed to the transaction yet.

Also, auto increment uses a special table lock and you have not commited the first transaction yet.

Try the test again, but with non-adjacent ids.

Thank you all. What I exactly want to know is that why there will be a lock? Only table with unique index will act like this.

You are blocking on name = '1'.

If either transaction decides to ROLLBACK, then the other could continue.  Hence, it is a "lock wait timeout", not a deadlock.

If either transaction COMMITs, then the other will get "Duplicate key name=1"



Actually, I want to know which kind of lock is used on the index "idx_test_name"?

Is that a special mechanism for unique index?

Hmmm...  I have never found a need to know, so I cannot answer your "which kind of lock" question.
